# aes decryption not working properly sometime

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am using aes for encryption/decryption of the text but sometime its giving me exact value after decryption while some times i am getting error. I referred to different answers over but didn't get the root cause of my problem .

```
private static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        // Declare the string used to hold the decrypted text.  
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an RijndaelManaged object  
        // with the specified key and IV.  
        using (var rijAlg = new System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged())
        {
            //Settings  
            rijAlg.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC;
            rijAlg.Padding = System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            rijAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;

            rijAlg.Key = key;
            rijAlg.IV = iv;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.  
            var decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            try
            {
                // Create the streams used for decryption.  
                using (var msDecrypt = new System.IO.MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (var csDecrypt = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {

                        using (var srDecrypt = new System.IO.StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream  
                            // and place them in a string.  
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                plaintext = "keyError";
            }
        }
        return plaintext;
    }
```

It throws error "**Padding is invalid and cannot be removed**" 
I seen some suggestion like to remove padding but it didn't seems proper solution.
I am not able to find the cause behind this as sometimes it runs perfectly without throwing error .

Any help or suggestion is really appreciated.

For Encryption - The encryption is being done on to client side in js and passing encryped text to server.

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("16 digit number here");
            var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("16 digit number here");
            var EncryptedString = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("entered string to encrypt"), key,
             { keySize: 128 / 8, iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });
```

Comment: This function looks pretty much ok to me, so the problem is likely to be in the *encryption* function you've not shown. Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: I added the encyption part which is done on client side .Is there any thing that we are doing encyption on client side and decryption on server side ?@Iridium

Answer (score 1):

By using a similar encryption routine in .NET to the decryption function you give I was able to successfully round-trip plaintext to ciphertext and back to plaintext, so it seems that the decryption function itself is ok. It therefore seems very likely that the key and/or IV you're using to encrypt does not match byte-for-byte with the values you're using when decrypting.

Given that your encryption code is using the UTF-8 encoded version of string values to form the key and IV, it would be worth doing the same in your decryption code (using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`).

However, it would be worth noting that whilst this might resolve the immediate issue, it is in itself a bad practice to use string values directly for keys without some form of key-derivation process (e.g. `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), and IVs should be generated randomly for *every* application of the encryption function. Those are just a few issues with your use of cryptography (and are independent of whether the code works or not).

Comment: Thnxs for ur suggestions , i am using UTF-8 encoded ver. while decryption alos . In addition for Key anf IV i am assigning the same value(random 16 digit's) , as you mentioned the following structure is working for me too , but while running multiple time , few times its throwing me Error as mentioned above. @Iridium

Comment: @user1260967 how is the ciphertext transferred between the encryption and decryption functions? You're likely corrupting the data somewhere in the process.

Comment: I found issue within my code itself , i was using different key for encryption and decryption by mistake. Thnxs for ur help !